# Array containing increasing ints

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

I've been on the following task for quite some time, but I cannot figure it out.

Given an array of scores, return true if each score is equal or greater than the one before. The array will be length 2 or more.

scoresIncreasing([1, 3, 4]) → true

scoresIncreasing([1, 3, 2]) → false

scoresIncreasing([1, 1, 4]) → true

One of my many attempts:

```
public boolean scoresIncreasing(int[] scores) {
  int i = 0;
  if(scores[i]<=scores[i+1]){
    i++;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

For some reason, the complier is not able to reach the "return false" statement.
Does anybody have any hints for me?
Edit: I dont think a loop is nescessary.
Edit number 2: I tried the following:

```
public boolean scoresIncreasing(int[] scores){
  for(int i=0;i<scores.length; i++){
    if(scores[i]<scores[i+1]){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

but it still only spits out true.

Answer (score 4):

In every one of your examples, `scores[0]<=scores[1]`.

Also, if you want to check more than the first two elements, you'll need a loop or recursion.

Answer (score 3):

> I dont think a loop is nescessary

It is (or recursion, but start with a loop). Your code only checks `scores[0] <= scores[1]`.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you start with a loop (as is, you only compare two numbers). You could begin your loop with the second score, if any score is less than the previous score your condition is `false` (and you can return it immediately). If you get to the end of the array, and none of the scores violate the condition return `true`. Like,

```
public static boolean scoresIncreasing(int[] scores) {
    for (int i = 1; i < scores.length; i++) {
        if (scores[i] < scores[i - 1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

In Java 8+, you *could* reduce that to a one-liner (assuming you always have more than one `int`) like

```
public static boolean scoresIncreasing(int[] scores) {
    return IntStream.range(1, scores.length)
            .allMatch(i -> scores[i] >= scores[i - 1]);
}
```

**or** add a guard for that condition like

```
if (scores.length < 2) return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a loop is necessary. Otherwise, you're just telling the compiler to check element 0 and element 1. You need to change your code to be

```
public boolean scoresIncreasing(int[] scores, int length)
    for(int i=0; i<length-1; i++) {
        if(scores[i]>scores[i+1])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

In response to edit 2: You're still returning true on the first check. Please see above code for reference!!!

Answer (score 0):

A loop (or recursion) is indeed necessary for this one, since you intend to check all the elements of the array. Without a loop, you can't use the new value of `i` you're incrementing, so that `i++` is useless, resulting in it only checking `scores[0]` and `scores[1]`. This is also why it always returns true: it doesn't check any more than the first two, and in you're example tests, all of the first two elements satisfy the conditions.

Edit: In your second edit, you're still returning true on the first satisfaction of your condition. This means that you're still only checking the first two elements. Instead, what you should do is logical-and each new result with a stored value and return *that* in the end, so that you don't return as soon as you see two values in increasing order.